# Can a heap be a complete tree?

Tags: algorithm, tree, heap

If I insert a new node under the node 6, the tree would still be a min-heap?

[image]

Comment: What do you think and why?

Comment: @MrSmith42 I think no because a heap mustn't be complete at the last level, but a guy put me in doubt.

Comment: Yes, it will be a min heap. Your sentence `because a heap mustn't be complete at the last level` is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) says:

> A binary heap is defined as a binary tree with two additional
>   constraints:[3]
>
> - Shape property: a binary heap is a complete binary tree; that is, all levels of the tree, except possibly the last one (deepest) are
>     fully filled, and, if the last level of the tree is not complete, the
>     nodes of that level are filled from left to right.
> - Heap property: the key stored in each node is either greater than or equal to (≥) or less than or equal to (≤) the keys in the node's
>     children, according to some total order.

If a heap couldn't be a complete binary tree, then it would be impossible to have a heap with a single item. Because a binary tree with one node is a complete binary tree.

The idea that the last level of a binary heap cannot be complete is just wrong. If that restriction existed, the math wouldn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

If the value to insert is at least 6, then yes, it will still be a min-heap. If the value is less than 6, it will not be a min-heap.

However, most heap insertion  algorithms will *always* insert the value there initially, i.e. at the next available position at the lowest level of the tree, or the first, left-most position of a new level, if the level is already full. Then the insertion process will continue to swap values until the value has [bubbled up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Insert) to a position where the min-heap property is valid again.

Answer (score 1):

After addition of every new element to the Heap, that element is need to be taken up to the root or any particular level above than its current level until all the nodes below it are greater than it.

***After reading your comment*** : 
A heap is by default a complete binary tree, and as far as I understand you might be talking about full binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

**It is a min-heap** :

All Root nodes of this tree is smaller than their Sub-nodes.

**It calls ALMOST COMPLETE BINARY TREE** :

In this tree (node=6) do not has two sub tree thats why we can't call this complete binary tree.

- **But,**(node=6)has a **left** sub tree, so that we can call this **"ALMOST BINARY COMPLETE TREE"**

A Heap can be a complete binary tree or an Almost complete binary tree.

if you add a number and the number>6 then it become complete binary tree.

Thank you.